# Preventing a routine that deletes a set of files from being destructive

Tags: c

The following is a small excerpt of a program I have written. The routine goes through `filenamelist` (permission 0600) which contains a list of line separated file names stored that are all stored in `directory` (like `FileOne\nAnotherFile\nThird file\n`) with the file extension `EXTENSION`. The list of file names comes from another part of my program.

I am a bit afraid that the `filenamelist` can be abused to delete other files on the system. Is there a better way of locking it down? Originally I stored the full path to the files that where to be deleted, but later separated and hardcoded the directory and file extension in an attempt to obfuscate it.

I am possibly being paranoid, but a malicious user (!) could poison the `filenamelist` with other file paths, somehow. For example `../../another-directory/donotdeleteme.sys` or escape it someway that I cannot even think of.

So can the below deletion routine be misused to delete files outside `directory`? Any suggestions on how I can lock it down further to prevent cat·astrophe?

PS: The program must *run as root* as part of it’s operation is modifying files outside the user’s home directory.

```
#define EXTENSION ".stuff"
char *directory = calloc( 28 );
directory = "/usr/local/share/stuffings/";
char *filenamelist = calloc( 24 );
filenamelist = "/etc/stuffing/files.lst";

void delete_files( char* filenamelist, char* directory ) {

  if ( access( filenamelist, F_OK | R_OK ) == 0 ) {
    FILE *filenamelist_fp = fopen( filenamelist, "r" );
    char filename[200];

    while( fgets( filename, 200, filenamelist_fp ) != NULL ) {
      char *pos;
      char *path = calloc( ( strlen( directory ) + strlen( filename ) + strlen( EXTENSION ) + 1 ), sizeof( char ) );

      if ( ( pos=strchr( filename, '\n' ) ) != NULL )
       *pos = '\0';

      strcat( path, directory );
      strcat( path, filename );
      strcat( path, EXTENSION );

      if ( access( path, F_OK | W_OK ) == 0 )
        unlink( path );
      free( path );
    }

    fclose( filenamelist_fp );
    unlink( filenamelist );
  }
} /* © */
```

Comment: `filenamelist = "/etc/stuffing/files.lst";` loses the handle to the memory you `calloc`ed the line before. You probably meant something like `strcpy(filenamelist, "/etc/...");`.

Comment: Please note that in unix '\n' is a valid character in filenames. Also: you could remember the sizes and use snprintf() instead of the strcat(). And the access() is useless, IMHO. And: to unlink a file you must have write access to the directory, which you don't check. And what Daniel says the same for dirname.

Comment: Never try security through obscurity. It's a bad idea that almost never works. Instead, do proven things like sandboxing, encryption, etc.

Comment: Allow this program to delete only files owned by user assuming the "stuffing" contain files created by same user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add a check to make sure there are no `/` characters embedded in the filename, then you will be perfectly safe against deleting files outside of the given directory (assuming a POSIX platform). Unfortunately this will also prevent deleting files in subdirectories under the given directory. If this is OK then you can use that solution.

If you need to support deleting files inside subdirectories of the given directory, then the first step is to block `..` from appearing as any component of the pathname, but that is not enough: you need to be careful of symlinks to directories anywhere under the given directory, because following them may lead to deleting files outside the tree. The most robust solution in this case is probably to parse each component of the pathname yourself, open each directory component manually using `openat` (comparing the result of `fstat` and `lstat` after the fact to make sure you didn't follow a symlink), and use `unlinkat` at the end to delete the file.

By the way, your call to `access( filenamelist, F_OK | R_OK)` is redundant and unnecessary. There is no point in testing access to the file before you open it. You might as well just `fopen()` the file.

Comment: Is forward slash the only thing I need to check for? Can it not be escaped somehow? I am thinking of web services where there are many ways to get around such simple tests using various ways of encoding/escaping a character.

Comment: Yes, / is the only thing you need to check for. No, it cannot be escaped. The rules for pathnames are a lot simpler than the rules for URLs.